# How can I access my file from a retrieved google cloud storage object in Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a function that saves to the Google cloud storage using the gcs client library. However after creating my file I can only retrieve a gcs object but not a file. This is how I write to the GCS and it works fine both for creating and retrieving objects. How do I access the file in an object ?

```
     result = urlfetch.fetch(url=google_sheet_link,
     method=urlfetch.GET,
     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'})

     gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                        'w',
                        content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel',

                        retry_params=write_retry_params)
     gcs_file.write(wb)
     gcs_file.close()
     self.tmp_filenames_to_clean_up.append(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

By object, I think you mean the `gcs_file` that is returned by `gcs.open`.  Think of that as just a temporary object that is never used again.

After you save your file, you use the filename to retrieve it.  For example:

```
f = gcs.open(filename, "r")
f.read(1024)
f.close()
```